# Property X does not exist on type 'Vue' when using this.$parent.somePropOrMethod and this.$root.somePropOrMethod

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, typescript-typings

When using VueJS with TypeScript, accessing a property or method via `this.$parent.somePropOrMethod` or `this.$root.somePropOrMethod` results in type error `Property somePropOrMethod does not exist on type 'Vue'`

The interface for `Vue` is

```
export interface Vue {
   ...
   readonly $parent: Vue;
   readonly $root: Vue;
   ...
   }
```

So how are we supposed to access properties and methods on the parent or root elements in a type-safe manner?

It seems like the interface should be `Vue & {[key: string]: any}` to allow for it unknown properties and methods on the `$root` and `$parent` properties.

Comment: Did you add a custom property to your element? If so you are kind of missing the point of typescript. If you want custom data on your Vue-elements (or any other element for that matter}, you should make a new class/interface which has those data types declared. Typescript is trying to make javascript a bit more strict, so you always know, ahead of time, what properties/methods are available.

Comment: To clarify more: These aren't custom properties. They are regular properties added to the parent components `data` option and `methods` option. VueJS understand `this.$parent.myProp` at runtime because it does exist on the parent component, but typescript can't figure it out.

Comment: Ohh, I see, this is the expected Vue flow. Please excuse me for being unaware of this. As @DavidJapan writes in his answer, to make an extension of the Vue class would probably be the most appropriate way to achieve this, and the cast your element to that class `(this.$parent as MyVueExtension).myProp`

Comment: I answered this question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002310/property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-combinedvueinstancevue-read/68505277#68505277. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 4):

For typescript type error , I usually solve by extending custom interface or setting as any . But I am not sure it is standard pattern ...

Custom Interface

```
export interface _Vue extends Vue {
  somePropOrMethod: any,
  forStringProp: String
}
```

Or setting as any

```
(this.$parent as any).somePropOrMethod
```

Comment: `(this.$parent as any).somePropOrMethod` you're right, I did try that and it works, but I was trying to avoid having to annotate every $parent type like that. I figured typescript should be able to inter it from the $parent's component options.

Comment: Yeah let wait other genius answer :>

Comment: I ended up using something similar to your solution since it works. I used `type VueExtensions = Vue & {[key: string]: any};` since this is generic to any possible property. Then `(this.$parent as VueExtensions ).somePropOrMethod` - until I hear a more official way, it gets the job done!

Comment: What is even more frustrating is that it doesn't seem that `(this.$parent as typeof MyParentComponent).somePropOrMethod` works either.