# Vue.js 3 and typescript : Property '$store' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Can't find anything to solve this seemingly obvious issue.

Just upgraded from Vue 2 to Vue 3 and Vuex with Typescript.

this.$store doesn't seem to be accessible, despite following the Vue 3 instructions.

> ERROR in src/components/FlashMessages.vue:28:25
> TS2339: Property '$store' does not exist on type 'ComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, { getAllFlashMessages(): Word; }, {}, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, ComponentOptionsBase<{}, {}, {}, { getAllFlashMessages(): Word; }, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, string, {}>>'.

```
    26 |     computed: {
    27 |         getAllFlashMessages (): FlashType {
  > 28 |             return this.$store.getters.getFlashMessages;
       |                         ^^^^^^
    29 |         },
    30 |     },
    31 |
```

main.ts

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './assets/styles/index.css'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

store.ts

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import FlashType from '@/init'

export default createStore({
    state: {
        flashMessages: [] as FlashType[],
    },

    getters: {
        getFlashMessages (state) {
            return state.flashMessages
        }
    },
```

FlashMessages.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import FlashType from "@/init";

export default defineComponent({
    name: "FlashMessages",

    data () {
        return {};
    },

    computed: {
        getAllFlashMessages (): FlashType {
            return this.$store.getters.getFlashMessages;
        },
    },
```

init.ts

```
export type FlashType = {
    kind: 'success' | 'error';
    message: string;
    time: number;
}
```

Any wisdom appreciated :)

File structure

```
├── .editorconfig
├── client
│   ├── babel.config.js
│   ├── CONTRACTS.md
│   ├── cypress.json
│   ├── jest.config.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── postcss.config.js
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── robots.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.vue
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   │   └── styles
│   │   │       └── index.css
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── admin
│   │   │   │   ├── AdminAdd.vue
│   │   │   │   ├── AdminList.vue
│   │   │   │   ├── AdminWord.vue
│   │   │   │   ├── EmotionAdd.vue
│   │   │   │   ├── EmotionsList.vue
│   │   │   │   └── Emotion.vue
│   │   │   └── FlashMessages.vue
│   │   ├── init.ts
│   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   ├── registerServiceWorker.ts
│   │   ├── router
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── shims-vue.d.ts
│   │   ├── store
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   └── views
│   │       ├── About.vue
│   │       ├── Admin.vue
│   │       ├── Emotions.vue
│   │       └── Home.vue
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── vue.config.js
├
└── server
    ├── api
    ├── api.bundle.js
    ├── index.ts
    ├── logger
    │   └── logger.ts
    ├── models
    ├── nodemon.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── router
    │   ├── db.ts
    │   └── emotions.ts
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── webpack.config.js
```

This is my first time properly using eslint, so I'm not sure if I've set it up correctly.. I ended up with a different tsconfig in /client and /server directories.

client/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: As a side note it's always worth it to have a look at the official repositories, as you may find information that will help you. For example the typing problem is currently documented [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/4.0) ^^.

Comment: Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002310/property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-combinedvueinstancevue-read/68505277#68505277.

Comment: According to the [official docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#augmenting-types-for-globalproperties) you may need to augmented types definition for the global store.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Next to `shims-vue.d.ts` file create another file called `shims-vuex.d.ts` with the following content :

```
import { Store } from '@/store';// path to store file

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store;
  }
}
```

For more check the [Typescript support](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#typescript-support) section for more details

Comment: Just adding a note, on VSCode I had to reload the window for this to work.

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar error but in VS Code.
As of Vuex 4, this is the preferred method:

```js
// vuex-shim.d.ts

import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  // Declare your own store states.
  interface State {
    count: number
  }

  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>
  }
}
```

Docs: https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/migrating-to-4-0-from-3-x.html#typescript-support

And I had to **disable then enable Vetur** again.

Comment: I did `F1 > Vetur > Restart VLS` which also did the trick, but your answer got me in the right direction!

Comment: This caused further errors for me, such as ` Could not find a declaration file for module './App.vue'`

Answer (score 3):

For those using VS Code and Vue with TypeScript via [vue-class-component](https://class-component.vuejs.org/) and/or [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) there may be no need in adding more type declarations. The issue could be solved with [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) . Namely with its `include` property.

You will see missing `this.$store` definition error if the file you are seeing this error is not in the list of globs in the `include` property.

Note as in the code below if you omit the `tests/...` glob from the `include` array the error will appear in the files matcing this glob. If you add the glob back the error will disappear.

```json
   "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/e2e/.fixtures/**/*.ts"]
```

Comment: This saved me time, than you !

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
app.provide("$store", store);
```

in your `main.ts` file before mounting. This method works on my side and the final code looks like

```
...
let app = createApp(App);
app.provide("$store", store);
app.use(store);
app.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing that the solutions above showed, but in addition, I created a globalProperty for the app.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$store = store;
app.use(router).mount('#app');
```

Comment: where and what was this file called? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems trying to configure vuex with typescript and options API. Regardless of the API you use, I strongly recommend you to use Pinia as it is a typescript ready solution and is very similar to Vuex

Answer (score -1):

Vuex doesn't provide typings for this.$store property out of the box. When used with TypeScript, you must declare your own module augmentation.
[Reference](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html)