# Vue.js 3 Property '$store' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using vue.js 3, typescript and vuex 4 for my project.
But I got this error when using `this.$store` on my `.vue` file

```
Property '$store' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, { exchanges: Exchange[]; isValidNodeUrl: boolean; isValidSelectedNetworks: boolean; web3: "" | Web3; privateKey: string; jsonKeystore: string; jsonKeystorePassword: string; ... 24 more ...; botIsRunning: boolean; }, ... 14 more ..., {}>'
```

I have added `vuex.d.ts` based on this document, but still got the same error
https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html .

```
import { Store } from "vuex";
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from "vue";

import { State } from "@/interfaces/bot";

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  // Declare your own store states.

  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>;
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: it should be named `shims-vuex.d.ts` as I said here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412243/vue-js-3-and-typescript-property-store-does-not-exist-on-type-componentpub/64414117#64414117

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim still same error after renamed it ..

Comment: Try out to restart the compiler and the editor

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yeah already did that few times ..

Comment: make sure  the 'vuex.d.ts' in 'src' folder

Answer (score -1):

check the tsconfig.json. possible there is an error on cannot identify the file.try to add file again by deleting again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30563027)