# Vue.js data variable does not exist

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm fairly new to Vue.js and run into an issue, which should be simple to solve, but I can't find an answer.

I use Vue.js with Ionic and have the following code.

```
<script lang="ts">
export default  {
  name: 'Tab1',
  components: { },
  data() {
    return {
      test: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    teMe () {
      this.test = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When running the code I get the following error: `Property 'test' does not exist on type '{ teMe(): void; }'.`

In the examples, I saw it is done the same way.
What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

Whats missing is "defineComponent()" so it should be:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Tab1',
....

})
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002310/property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-combinedvueinstancevue-read.

Comment: Yes, I am, but my method does not return anything.

Comment: Try using `void` as the return type.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with your code it really makes sense, But I think those spaces might cause the problem if you don't have the right extensions.
So please consider this.

```
export default  {
  name: 'Tab1',
  data: function() {
    return {
      test: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    tome(): boolean {
      this.test = !this.test;
  },
  }
}
```

then have a button to test that:

```
<button @click="tome">click me</button>
```

please note that Html is not case sensitive.
and Vue used to automatically turn this method declaration **toMe** into this **to-me**.
don't know if it's still doing that!?
So please avoid capital letters and other symbols!
Be careful.

Comment: That did not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: edited my code to specify the return type of the function as TypeScript doesn't tolerate that.